# How to make google ml kit to recognize driver license barcode?

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I am trying out google_ml_kit flutter package for Android to get information from driver license barcode.

I am testing it using the sample app from mlkit:
https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/tree/master/example

The code that returns the list of scanned barcodes is here:

`final barcodes = await barcodeScanner.processImage(inputImage);`

Full code is in:
https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/blob/master/example/lib/VisionDetectorViews/barcode_scanner_view.dart

Scanned my driver license barcode but the barcode is always recognized as BarcodeType.Text instead of BarcodeType.driverLicense.

Now I do know that BarcodeDriverLicense does exist in this package:
https://pub.dev/documentation/google_ml_kit/latest/google_ml_kit/BarcodeDriverLicense-class.html

I don't know how to make the scanned barcode to be recognized as driver license bar code.

Is there a step that I missed?

Thank you

Comment: What is the drivers license you are trying to scan? We don't support all, in which case you need to do the parsing yourself, until it is supported.

Comment: Hi Chrisito, I am currently trying to scan Texas Driver License.
Is there a list of what US states driver license mlkit supported?

Comment: @Chrisito I found out why the driver license barcode wasn't read as DL barcode type. 
It was because CameraController was using ResolutionPreset.low. It should be at least ResolutionPreset.medium.
I found out about this after I tried out the trial scanner SDK of other product which had the camera in higher res when doing the scan.
The google mlkit example needs to update its CameraController's ResolutionPreset. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my detailed answer in the comment above.
In short, the solution is to have CameraController's ResolutionPreset to be set to ResolutionPreset.medium at the minimum.

Hope this helps others.

[Edit]
Just read this and have a better understanding why higher res is needed for PDF417 scanning.
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android